# \n not working .new line not working in unity C#x

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I run the game `something 3` doesn't get appended because it is after the `\n`.

I have tried it with single `\n`.

```
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
      {
         text.text= "something 1"+
                    "something 2 \n\n"+
                     "something 3";
      }
}
```

There are no compiler errors.

Comment: What is your desired behavior? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Your UI Text element may not be big enough. Try increasing the Height of the element or changing "Vertical overflow" to overflow:
[Set vertical overflow to overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNqRB.png)